# Component for Vue.js 3 to add sorting, filtering and pagination to the table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've been researching for a while but can't seem to find an up to date component for Vue.js 3 that adds sorting, filtering and pagination to the table. Frontend already has all the data, no additional requests to backend API are needed.

So far what I saw was either out of date, or for Vue 1/2, or not free or a part of a bigger frameworks.

Does anybody know if such component exists?

Here's an overview of what I saw during my research:

- [vuetifyjs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/) - data table component is still under development and is a part of a bigger framework.
- [quasar](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar) - has a table component but as a part of a framework.
- [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table) - last official release was more than a year ago and doesn't seem to support Vue 3.
- [vue-dataset](https://github.com/kouts/vue-dataset) - there is no official release with the support for Vue 3 yet.
- [vue-good-table](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table) - there is no official release with the support for Vue 3 yet.
- [vuejs-smart-table](https://github.com/tochoromero/vuejs-smart-table) - last official release was 2.5 years ago.
- [vue-jd-table](https://github.com/jamesdruhan/vue-jd-table) - the only official release was 4 years ago.
- [coreui](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/smart-table.html) - only in paid version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use community (free) version of [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) which has fresh releases, supports Vue 3 and has functionality for pagination, filtration and sorting.

It required some additional setup and styling, but it's still better than other alternatives that I saw.

Just in case, it also works with Angular, React and native JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

[Primevue's DataTable component](https://primevue.org/datatable/) is perfect for this

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Do I understand correctly that this component is free?

Comment: The whole components library is free

Comment: Hm, I'm following the guide on primevue website, but whatever I do, when I try to render DataTable with Columns I get the warning 
`[Vue warn]: Property "cx" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.` 
and is followed with the exception
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.cx is not a function` which is triggered from datatable.esm.js.
Maybe you know what could be the issue?

Comment: That is weird, browsing through their code `cx` is definitely defined in `BaseComponent` and the datatable components do extend that

Answer (score 0):

Use this data table

https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-table-vue-v3

it has some many advance features and completely free!

compatible with vue 2 and vue 3 both